# Double condition with PXDefault

Tags: acumatica

In the SOInvoice, I would like use a double condition for this field :
PX.Objects.SO.SOLine - TaxCategoryID

If the branchid=5 and TaxCategoryID=1000 then TaxCategory=2000
I don't know if I must use the event, or the attribut configuration.

Thanks

```
[PXDefault(typeof(Search<InventoryItem.taxCategoryID,
Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<SOLine.inventoryID>>>>),
PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing, SearchOnDefault = false)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLine_InventoryID field updated event calls SetDefaultExt to the tax category field.   You could write an override at the graph level for TaxCategory like this....

```
protected virtual void _(Events.FieldDefaulting<SOLine, taxCategoryID> e, PXFieldDefaulting baseMethod)
{
    SOLine row = e.Row as SOLine;
    if (row.BranchID) == 5
          e.NewValue = "1000";
    else
          e.NewValue = "2000"
}
```

This is pseudo-code but I think you see how it functions.  Be sure to include the delegate, so that only your override executes and not thebase FieldDefaulting event

[Field Defaulting Event per Acumatica Wiki](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(2))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=6db70fe7-3fc3-4e05-d3a6-5ecb93bea6a9)

Comment: also need PXFormula for Default<fieldschanging> since PXDefault only fires once. This way as user sets or changes inventory id or tax category you can still get your default event to run.  Also side note, no need to cast e.Row to SOLine as it is already of type SOLine - can just use e.Row as benefits for using Events.Row/Field signature

Comment: Old habits die hard.  I know what you mean regarding the cast